# Django: how to get url path?

Tags: python, django, url, path, reverse

I've read something about `reverse` function but I don't get it.

Two of my urls are calling the same view.
In this view I need to decide the context based on the url.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('view/', my_view),
    path('edit/', my_view),
]
```

views.py:

```
def my_view(request):
    #some code
    if(my_url_path == 'view/'):  #just taking a look
        context = {
            'task': 'view'
        }
    elif(my_url_path == 'edit/'):  #can edit
        context = {
            'task': 'edit'
        }
```

I don't use two different views for these paths because its code is very extensive and I can save many repeated lines (DRY). They do something very similar and I can adjust these small differences in the template based in the context that the view is sending.

How can I do what I showed in the view? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The best practice would be to break it into two different views and move the common code elsewhere.

But if you want to access the path you can just call `request.path_info` as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path)

Alternatively you could use a capture group on the [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/) to simplify further, provided the url pattern is unique to others in your urls.py. Something along the following

urls.py:

```
path('<task>/', my_view, name='my_view'),
```

views.py

```
def my_view(request, task):
    context = { 'task': task }
```

Comment: I know it and this is the first time I need to not to break it in two different views. As I said their code are very very close, the only difference is that I need to get if it is viewing data or editting it (the form is the same), ir order to make it (or not) "readonly" with JavaScript by reading if the path is "edit/" or "view/". I'm gonna check that document, thank you!

Comment: good luck, just edited my answer to include a second possible solution that may cut down on the code required

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('view/', my_view, 'first_url'),
    path('edit/', my_view, 'second_url'),
]
```

in view

```
from django.urls import resolve


def my_view(request):
   current_url = resolve(request.path_info).url_name

   if(current_url == 'first_url'):  #just taking a look
        context = {
            'task': 'view'
        }
   elif(current_url == 'second_url'):  #can edit
        context = {
            'task': 'edit'
        }
```

hope it helps

Comment: I'm having the following error: "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"

Comment: which version of django you are using

Comment: I'm using 2.1.7.

Comment: @c.grey it works, thank you. I didn't used the context as the same as yours because my project is different. But the approach is working.